# Electron > Is this a bug?

Tags: html, electron

I have this html structure :

```html
<div class="wrapper2">
   <div class="previewContainer2">
    <div id="previewGroup">
     <div id="filePreview">
      <div id="icon">
       <div id="whiteSheet"/>
       <div id="extension">EXT</div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <img id="thumbnail" src="assets/indesign.svg" />
     <div id="fileName">aaa</div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="metadataContainer2">
   </div>
  </div>
```

But then once loaded in electron, the last div (.metadataContainer2) is moved inside the .previewContainer2 div :\

```html
<div class="wrapper2">
   <div class="previewContainer2">
    <div id="previewGroup">
     <div id="filePreview">
      <div id="icon">
       <div id="whiteSheet">
       <div id="extension">EXT</div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <img id="thumbnail" src="assets/indesign.svg">
     <div id="fileName">aaa</div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="metadataContainer2">
    <p>ncndnlkcd</p>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Did I do something wrong ?

Comment: Check what happens to your `<div id="whiteSheet"/>`. This might be the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you follow the HTML5 rules a `div` tag can not be self closed. Check more on [this site](http://xahlee.info/js/html5_non-closing_tag.html)

So modify your original code `line#6` to mentioned below.

`<div id="whiteSheet"></div>`

Comment: Oh sure, too much XML history here :D Thank you a lot :)